# check if requestAnimationFrame is working

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

How I can check if requestAnimationFrame is working? I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly.I have read that the animation should stop when window is not visible to user if requestAnimationFrame is used correctly.But my animation is working even when website is not visible to me.So I'm pretty sure that I'm not using it correctly.Here's the code that I'm using.

```
var SIV=v.leavingSection ;
var requestAnimationFrame= window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                           window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                           window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                           window.msRequestAnimationFrame ;

function sectionMovement(delay,section) { 
 setTimeout(function sectionMovementTimeout() {
 var val=((v.sectionIndex + 1) > v.leavingSection) ? val = 100 : val = 0 ;
document.getElementById("sec_"+section+"").style.transform="translate3d(0,-"+val+"%,0)";
requestAnimationFrame(sectionMovementTimeout)}
,delay)};
for (var i = 0; i < v.absDistance ; i++) {
sectionMovement(i*750,((v.sectionIndex + 1) > v.leavingSection) ? (SIV + 1) : SIV );
((v.sectionIndex + 1) > v.leavingSection) ? SIV++ : SIV-- };
```

I will really appreciate any suggestion

Comment: iirc it's not that it stops execution when the window loses focus, it's just that it's called significantly less often.

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/efficient-animations-with-requestanimationframe   scroll down until you see "Animations Only Run When Visible"

Comment: Also, it's not the same that the window is minimized than when window is normal but there are other windows on top of it.